# How to call Rest API with Content and Headers in c#?

Tags: c#, rest

I am trying to call Rest API with content and headers in c#. Actually I am trying to convert to c# from Python code which is:

```
import requests
url = 'http://url.../token'
payload = 'grant_type=password&username=username&password=password'
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
response = requests.request('POST', url, headers = headers, data = payload, allow_redirects=False)
print(response.text)
```

So far I am trying with:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Url);

var tmp = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
    Content =
            {

            }
     };

    var result = client.PostAsync(Url, tmp.Content).Result;
}
```

I have no idea how to put from Python code Headers (Content-Type) and additional string (payload).

Comment: I gave you an answer based on HttpClient. Please check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a sample I use in one of my apps:

```
_client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigManager.Api.BaseUrl), 
                           Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, -1) };

_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                     new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Bearer", "some token goes here");
```

Comment: Yes something like this, how did you solve setting like timeout=undefined and allow_redirects=False

Comment: @DaniKR like this: _client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigManager.Api.BaseUrl), Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, -1) };

Comment: Just specify the timeout you want

Answer (score 3):

If you use [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/), you should be able to call your service with the following code snipped

```
var client = new RestClient("http://url.../token");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "grant_type=password&username=username&password=password", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var result = response.Content;
```

I based my answer on the anwser of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46945038/597028).

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Net.Http;

var content = new StringContent("grant_type=password&username=username&password=password");
content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
client.PostAsync(Url, content);
```

---

Or use [`FormUrlEncodedContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/api/system.net.http.formurlencodedcontent?view=netframework-4.7.2) without set header

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"grant_type", "password"},
    {"username", "username"},
    {"password", "password"}
};
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);
client.PostAsync(Url, content);
```

---

If you write UWP application, use `HttpStringContent` or `HttpFormUrlEncodedContent` instead in Windows.Web.Http.dll.

```
using Windows.Web.Http;

var content = new HttpStringContent("grant_type=password&username=username&password=password");
content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
client.PostAsync(Url, content);
```

---

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"grant_type", "password"},
    {"username", "username"},
    {"password", "password"}
};
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);
client.PostAsync(Url, content);
```

Comment: What reference I have to use for "HttpFormUrlEncodeContent"?

Comment: Windows.Web.Http.dll. I've also add code for normal .net api.

Comment: You made it look as though you can't specify your data and headers at the same time. That is not correct.