# Cookies is stored but not be used to log in. Error: Login Session is expired, you must login again

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, session-cookies

I am new at c#, when I call api to a uri, it asks me to store cookies after logging in at the login uri. I have stored it by using static variable. But still can't login. It still shows the error:

> Session Login is expired, you must login again, when i print out
> cookies, same cookie at 2 request, login uri, eg: JSESSION:
> 512F582H395D465BAFDF63B0D5D21C16.

Anyone can check for me? Thank you.

````
        static Uri uri = new Uri("http://myurl.com/login"); //example uri
        static Uri uri1 = new Uri("http://myurl.com/listMap");

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            await Login_ClickAsync();

            foreach (Cookie cookie in cookieContainer.GetCookies(uri))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cookie0:" + cookie.ToString());
            }
        }

        static CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();


        static HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {

            CookieContainer = cookieContainer
        };

        static HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
        static async Task Login_ClickAsync()
        {


            client.DefaultRequestHeaders
                          .Accept
                          .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            // add API method parameters
            keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("userName", "testaccount"));
            keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "123456"));
            HttpContent multiForm = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);

            //request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            HttpResponseMessage resposne = await client.PostAsync(uri, multiForm);

            //CookieContainer _cookieContainer = 

            cookieContainer = GetCookies(resposne); ;

            if (resposne.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {


                foreach (Cookie cookie in cookieContainer.GetCookies(uri))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Cookie1:" + cookie.ToString());
                }

                await getData();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("False");
            }

        }
        public static CookieContainer GetCookies(HttpResponseMessage response)
        {
            var pageUri = response.RequestMessage.RequestUri;
            var _cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            IEnumerable<Cookie> responseCookies = cookieContainer.GetCookies(uri).Cast<Cookie>();
            foreach (Cookie c in responseCookies)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Coookie111:" + c);
                _cookieContainer.Add(pageUri, c);
            }
            return _cookieContainer;
        }
        static async Task getData()
        {


            var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            HttpContent multiForm = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);

            HttpResponseMessage resposne = await client.PostAsync(uri1, multiForm);

            if (resposne.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string response1 = await resposne.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(response1.ToString());


                foreach (Cookie cookie in cookieContainer.GetCookies(uri1))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Cookie2:" + cookie);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("False");
            }

        }
    }```
````

Comment: A quick question before attempting to answer, is RestSharp suitable for your program? for calling api from c#. if possible check this link https://restsharp.dev/usage/authenticators.html#using-simpleauthenticator

Comment: How can i pass request body by application/x-www-form-urlencoded ? @BijuKalanjoor

Comment: Thats possible with Restsharp ,please check the shared document,  definitely possible

Comment: https://restsharp.dev/usage/parameters.html#get-or-post here also mentioned deferent type of request parameters

Comment: only json and xml body, not application/x-www-form-urlencoded :( @BijuKalanjoor

Comment: Nop, please check the second link too. read it care fully

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45238899/restsharp-post-request-body-with-x-www-form-urlencoded-values

Comment: @BijuKalanjoor oh, thank you bro, i tried using RestSharp and it work

Comment: Yeahh, bro... it should work. i wish wish you a bright future in c#